# ¿Cómo implementar en javascript lo de arrastrar y soltar para modificar la ruta de Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, rutas

Tengo en mi página web una parte con `Google Maps` usando su `API` de `Javascript`.

En dos cuadros de texto se introduce el origen y el destino y en el mapa aparece la ruta.

Me gustaría saber si usando la `API` se puede implementar la funcionalidad que tiene `Google Maps` de modificar una ruta arrastrando y soltando un punto cualquiera de la ruta.

Comment: La pregunta no es del todo buena ya que no incluye lo buscado/investigado como se require en [ask].

Comment: Lo siento, para la próxima vez lo hare mejor. Por cierto muchas gracias por solucionarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí se puede. La documentación oficial incluye un ejemplo el cual se encuentra en inglés en la siguiente dirección:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable?hl=es-419

La documentación sobre el Servicio de Direcciones de la API de JavaScript de Google Maps incluye una sección sobre esto, la cual la puedes encontrar en .

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=es-419#DraggableDirections